# 64 bit conversion iOS / How to handle 3rd party libraries like AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, afnetworking

I'm in the process of adapting an existing project to support 64 bit. How exactly should 3rd party libraries be handled? For example i'm using a relativly old AFNetworking version (1.1.0). What is the best practises? Do i just look for each library if there is a 64 bit optimized version and replace it within my project? I actually don't want to just replace every library because something else could potentially break this way. Would be nice to get some feedback on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to look for 64-bit clean updates of these libraries. The only alternative is making those libraries 64-bit safe yourself. You can also try to make no changes and just compile for 64-bit too. But then you might have bugs introduced by that.